# jquery function onclick (span class) from jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

hi jquery folks I have a jquery datepicker from jqueryui.com/datepicker/‎. Now i want to add some custom features to it.
The first question, If I enter the source of my page i cannot see the printed jquery code. 
Only when I inspect the element(in opera) I can see the printed html. I hope this is not a problem..

When i click on the Next (span)button, i want to do some things. But the problem is I am not able to attach a function to the span class. I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e').click(function(){
window.alert("it works");
});
});
```

this code appears when I inspect the element:

```
   <a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-next-hover"  data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next">ev
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>
  </a>
```

How can this function on click work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have the selector wrong

`.ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e`

Looks for a element with class `ui-icon-circle-triangle-e` inside another element with class `ui-icon`.

When you want to select an element that has more than one class applied to it they need to be seperated by a period `.`

use

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e",function(){
   window.alert("it works");
});
```

or just

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon",function(){
   window.alert("it works");
});
```

Comment: it makes sense but it doesnt work, is it because it is not printed in source code?

Comment: @RobinHo by the edit of your code you took out the `$("body").on` part you need that as it delegates events to new elements that have been created

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling it properly, it needs to be:

```
$('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e').click(function(){
    alert ('it works');
});
```

You made a blank instead of a point between your two classes in jquery.

Comment: sorry this doesnt work. is it because it is not printed in source code?

Comment: hmm, normally it should work. you put it in the ready function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e').off('click').on('click',function(){
alert("Working");
});
});
```

If you are attaching event directly on the element better to use off and on.

Cheers !!